# C language: Parallel threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

Basically I've got two sockets that I'd like to run in parallel, so I don't have to wait for one socket to send data to receive data from the other etc.
I can do this easily by forking, but, to be tidier, I'd like to know if there is a way to do it from the same process.

Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
void test(){
         sleep(5000);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("%d\n",time(NULL));
  test();
  printf("%d\n",time(NULL));
  system("PAUSE");
  return 0; 
}
```

But both lines of output would be the same, as the sleep function is being processed 'somewhere else'.

I found an MSDN document about creating threads, but it talked about C-library functions not being safe for it, which worried me, I like my stdlib!

So, yeah, if you have any examples, you can just use sleep() as a placeholder, I'm pretty good with sockets :) I'm on Windows, but a Unix version would be nice as well, or better yet, one that works with both.

EDIT: Thanks for all your responses.
I think I see what you mean: I have my two sockets, then I call select(), it returns all the sockets that are ready to receive/send data, I send/receive my data, then loop back.
However, how could I implement this with accept(), as the socket hasn't yet been created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach is to make the sockets non-blocking, and use `select()` and/or `WaitForMultipleObjects()` to check for when you can read/write more data from/to each socket. That way the application can remain single-threaded while still appearing to service multiple sockets at the same time.

Comment: Exactly! I would rather stay away from threads as much as possible. For I/O-bound tasks using asynchronous I/O seems to be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can using omp sections or use pthread/WinThread

Answer (score 0):

Or on Unix the normal solution would be [fork()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28operating_system%29)

Comment: Isn't fork too much coarse grain for this ?

Comment: @Joel - possibly select would be better - but for a large server fork() is normal

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works (or has an analog) on Windows, but there's always [select](http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc750/html/lr2/select.htm).